# ajax is loading the page to return a POST request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When i make a "POST" request through ajax, the page is loading when returning the request.

Don't we use ajax to prevent the entire page to reload ?

This is my html code:

```
<form method="post">
<div align="center" class="col-md-10">
    <input  type="text" id= "input" name="input" >
 </div><
 <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="search">
     Search
    </button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

and this is my ajax request:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".search").on('click', function () {
            var data = {};
            data['input'] = $('#input').val();
            // Submit data via AJAX§
            $.ajax({
            url: '/home',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                    }
            });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Do anyone knows how to fix this problem and what i am doing wrong !!!

Comment: Because submit buttons submit the page.

Comment: class `search` doesn't exist. on you JS try `$("#search")` instead of `$(".search")`

Comment: Simply change the button type to Button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, you have `search` as id not class. Its not calling ajax at all.
It is getting submit because its a `submit` button, so change your code like this,

**Note:** `.search` will not work,

```
$("#search").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {};
    data['input'] = $('#input').val();
        // Submit data via AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
});
```

`e.preventDefault()` is used to prevent the default behaviour of submit button(By default on click of submit button will reload the page.)see more about `e.preventDefault()` , [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Comment: You're right, but it's probably worth explaining `e.preventDefault()` as simply selecting by ID will not stop the form being submitted.

Comment: @Archer I was about add the link for that. Will add now.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju thanks for your answer, but the page is still loading after lake a request

Comment: did u change `.search` to `#search`??

Comment: changing this, it should work fine. It's working for me.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

you are using Id and picking the class which is wrong.

use

```
$("#search").on('click', function (e) {
```

instead of

```
$(".search").on('click', function (e) {
```

so the final JS would be

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var data = {};
        data['input'] = $('#input').val();
        // Submit data via AJAX§
        $.ajax({
        url: '/home',
                type: 'post',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is **OK**.
You just need to add [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to the `click` function, and change from `.search` to `#search`, i.e..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = {};
            data['input'] = $('#input').val();
            // Submit data via AJAX§
            $.ajax({
            url: '/home',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                    }
            });
    });
    });
</script>
```

---

event.preventDefault()

> This method does not accept any arguments.
>   For example, clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL.
>   We can use event.isDefaultPrevented() to determine if this method has
>   been called by an event handler that was triggered by this event

Answer (score 0):

If you need to submit form without page load you need to prevent the default behavior of the button:

```
$(your_button).on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to return `false` in your onclick event handler to stop the form being submitted:

```
$(".search").on('click', function () {
    var data = {};
    data['input'] = $('#input').val();
    // Submit data via AJAX§
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Please also check this to get more information about the [difference between `return false;` and `e.preventDefault();`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/3647441)

Comment: Not sure why this warranted uncommented downvotes.  Sure, misses that the `on` handler will never get hit due to the wrong selector, but the `return false` information is just as important.

Answer (score -1):

Use type="button" instead of submit. 
Submit button will submit the form as it is.